# Join Multiple tables : Edit and Update an Item from a table list to a modal in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and I'm having trouble editing an item and showing it in a modal form and updating it in the database. The data is not showing in a modal. The data is coming from different tables in the database.

Expected output: show the list in a single view(table) and edit a selected item from the list (modal) and update it.

Here's my code:

AdminController:

```
    public JsonResult EditItem(int? itemID)
    {
        var id = db.Items.Where(i => i.ItemID == itemID).FirstOrDefault();

        List<Item> itemList = db.Items.ToList();
        List<ItemDetail> itemDetailList = db.ItemDetails.ToList();
        List<ProductType> productTypeList = db.ProductTypes.ToList();

        var details = from itm in itemList
                      join itmDetail in itemDetailList on itm.ItemID equals itmDetail.ItemID into ItemInfo
                      from itmDetail in ItemInfo.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      join product in productTypeList on itmDetail.ProductID equals product.ProductID into ProductInfo
                      from product in ProductInfo.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      where itm.ItemID.Equals(id)
                      select new TableCollection { Item = itm, ItemDetail = itmDetail, ProductType = product };

        return Json(details, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditItem(Item item, ItemDetail details)
    {
        ItemDetail itmDetails = db.ItemDetails.Where(d => d.ItemID == item.ItemID).FirstOrDefault();

        itmDetails.ItemID = details.ItemID;
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Inventory", "Admin");
    }
```

InventoryList View:

```
@model IEnumerable<VetClinic.Models.Admin.TableCollection>

@if (Model != null)
{
    <table id="inventory" class="table table-striped table-hover">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th>Product Type</th>
                <th>Item Name</th>
                <th># of Stock</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="bg-light">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr id="row_@item.ItemDetail.ItemID">
                    <td>@item.ProductType.Name @item.ProductType.Type</td>
                    <td>@item.ItemDetail.ItemName</td>
                    <td>@item.ItemDetail.NumOfStock</td>
                    <td>@item.ItemDetail.Price</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" id="edit" onclick="EditItem(@item.Item.ItemID)"><i class="fa fa-pencil" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit" style="color: blue;"></i></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <div class="modal fade" id="EditItem" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="EditItem" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Edit Item</h5>

                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("EditItem", "Admin", FormMethod.Post))
                    {
                        <input type="hidden" id="hiddenItemID" />
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-lg-3">
                                <label>Product Type:</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                                <input type="text" id="productType"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-lg-2">
                                <label>Item Name:</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-3">
                                <input type="text" id="itemName" class="form-control" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-lg-5">
                                <label>Number of Stocks</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-2">
                                <input type="text" id="numOfStocks" class="form-control" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-lg-2">
                                <label>Price:</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-3">
                                <input type="text" id="price" class="form-control" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
else
{
    <i class="fa fa-info-circle">&nbsp;</i>@ViewBag.EmptyList;
}

<script>
    function EditItem(id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Admin/EditItem/" + id,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                $("#hiddenItemID").val(response.ItemID);
                $("#EditItem").modal("show");
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: what is the error and where is it ?

Comment: if it is in front end error I meant then open console please and show us the error or show compiler error

Comment: if you have no error at all and data is just not shown those modal opens? or It open and you can not just submit?